# Serve a download of an uploaded file in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

My Symfony2 app allows users to upload files. I'd like to users to also be able to download their files.

If I were doing straight PHP, I'd just output the appropriate headers, then output the contents of the file. How would I do this within a Symfony2 controller?

(If you use a hard-coded filename in your answer, that's good enough for me.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
/** 
 * Serves an uploaded file.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/file", name="event_file")
 * @Template()
 */
public function fileAction($id)
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('VNNPressboxBundle:Event')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Event entity.');
    }   

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => $entity->getDocument()->getMimeType(),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$entity->getDocument()->getName().'"'
    );  

    $filename = $entity->getDocument()->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$entity->getDocument()->getName();

    return new Response(file_get_contents($filename), 200, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: if you are using Symfony master you should use [makeDisposition](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation.html#downloading-files)

Comment: @1ed- but that's only in the 2.1 branch, not the 2.0 branch. The 2.1 branch is not yet stable.

Comment: @Jason - You could also [stream the response](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) but it's only available in the 2.1 branch.

Comment: Thanks ALOT! I tried everything else but it allways said that the file could not be found... but yours is working! +1

Comment: @Jason Swett What if the file is huge, wont it cause out of memory issue ?

Comment: With a `ParamConverter`, you can get rid of the first 8 lines of this function. http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why you do not want to bypass Symfony entirely and just serve the file via your HTTP server (Apache, Nginx, etc)?

Just have the uploaded files dropped somewhere in the document root and let your HTTP server do what it does best.

**Update:** While the Symfony2 code posted by @[Jason Swett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9968849/3765) will work for 99% of cases - I just wanted to make sure to document the alternative(s). Another way of securing downloads would be to use the [`mod_secdownload`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModSecDownload) module of Lighttpd. This would be the ideal solution for larger files or files that need to be served quickly with little-as-possible memory usage.

Comment: That would be a good idea, except I only want certain users to be able to access certain files.

Comment: @JasonSwett: No problem, I also added an update to my answer with another alternative. Loading a file into memory (`file_get_contents()`) just to send it to the user's browser may work for many cases - but not all.

Comment: with nginx you use the X-Accel-Redirect Header `$response->headers->set('X-Accel-Redirect', $path);` and create an internal nginx rule.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/downloads/serving_files_with_a_controller.md)

It will allow you to do this:

```
/**
 * @param integer $assetId
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function downloadAssetAction($assetId)
{
    if (!$courseAsset = $this->get('crmpicco.repository.course_asset')->findOneById($assetId)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Requested asset (' . $assetId . ') does not exist.');
    }

    $downloadHandler = $this->get('vich_uploader.download_handler');

    return $downloadHandler->downloadObject($courseAsset->getFile(), 'assetFile', null, $courseAsset->getName());
}
```